# List WiFi networks on Android Q / API 29

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-10.0

I'm currently migrating my application to Android Q.  I want to list all configured WiFi networks and before Q I was able to do so with the function [getConfiguredNetworks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()) from the WiFiManager. Sadly this method was deprecated on API level 29 and returns an empty list on Android Q devices.

The deprecation comment only refers to cases where I also want to connect to these networks. I do not want to do this, I just want to list the networks with their name and get their internal `id`. Do you have any ideas how I should do this in Q?

Comment: documentaion at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager
says

This method was deprecated in API level 29. a) See WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build() for new mechanism to trigger connection to a Wi-Fi network.

Comment: I do not want to connect to a network, just list all configured ones with their name

Comment: have you given location permissions?

Comment: Is it possible to enable wifi on API 29? Can someone please check and answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075918/how-to-programatically-enable-wifi-on-android-10-devices ?

Comment: See "[Restrictions on direct access to configured Wi-Fi networks](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#configure-wifi)" in the Android 10 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is No way to get Configured WiFi Networks in Android Q and Above. The only is to get the currently available networks using `getScanResults()` I know this wont actually solve the issue for getting the configured network names. Instead only gets the currently available networks.

```
    List<ScanResult> results = null;
    TextView outputs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputs);
    try{
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        int len = results.size();
        String res = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            res = outputs.getText() + "\n" + results.get(i).SSID;
            outputs.setText(res);

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("MainActivity",e.getMessage());
    }
```

Currently they are only providing mechanism to trigger connection to a WiFi Network as per their documentations. Lets hope something comes up or not

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that there is no way...Android is getting too sandboxed. I am trying to just notify the user that they've lost connection a particular wifi device. But the Apis above 26 are getting so limited with wireless control.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, and my problem was that I has mi targetSdkVersion in 30! and the function  getConfiguredNetworks was deprecated in api 29, when I run my app in a android 9 devices or below, works great but when I run my app into android 10, the function getConfiguredNetworks return null or empty list,
my solution was change my targetSdkVersion to 28, like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "asdaadsda"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

References: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()

Comment: so, did this work on newer SDK versions?
As, it is already said that won't work above APK Level 29