# Is it possible to programmatically enable wifi on Android 10 devices?

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager, android-10.0

Since [setWifiEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)) is deprecated on Android 10, how does one programatically enable wifi on Android 10 devices?

Is it not possible to programmatically enable wifi at all on Android 10+ (SDK 29) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning on wifi using WifiManager stops to work on Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075596/turning-on-wifi-using-wifimanager-stops-to-work-on-android-10)

Comment: I guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/63262649/2677764 might help you with the WiFi toggling issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, This is not possible to `enable` or `disable` Wi-Fi `programmatically` from `Android-10` `API level 29` [**Until google provides an alternative solution**].

> For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always return false and will have no effect.
>
> If apps are targeting an older SDK ( Build.VERSION_CODES.P or below), they can continue to use this API.

There is an [issue 128554616](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128554616) which already has been  created in `google issuetracker` forum. You can see there for any updated info.

Comment: Ah, the API itself is take away. This turned out more interesting than I thought :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer with an `issuetracker` which is already created in google forum. hope you can find more info from thers. Happy Coding.

Comment: Google answered with a "Won't Fix (Intended behavior)". This is worse each android update.

Comment: I am using the  val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
            wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true   FOR ENABLING THE WIFI in android 8 BUT its not working. Any other option

Answer (score 6):

Now in android 10 you can do like this

```
Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY);
startActivityForResult(panelIntent);
```

**ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY**
Shows settings related to internet connectivity, such as Airplane mode, Wi-Fi, and Mobile Data.

**ACTION_WIFI**
Shows Wi-Fi settings, but not the other connectivity settings. This is useful for apps that need a Wi-Fi connection to perform large uploads or downloads.

**ACTION_NFC**
Shows all settings related to near-field communication (NFC).

**ACTION_VOLUME**
Shows volume settings for all audio streams.

Comment: This doesn't answer "How to programaticaly enable wifi on 10+", but does give the nearest available option targeting SDK 29.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is! Google is giving the answer pretty clearly:

> If apps are targeting an older SDK ( Build.VERSION_CODES.P or below), they can continue to use this API.

Change your API to 28 and it works great. Or if you need a solution for Apps like **Tasker** or **Automate** see my post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65022589/14712690