# RemoveNetworkSuggestions does not disconnect from WiFi Android

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I'm trying to disconnect from WiFi network inside the function `disconnectWiFi()` using `removeNetworkSuggestions` but the device still stays connected to the network. I tried passing a null ArrayList as well as a list that contains the NetworkSuggestion to the `RemoveNetworkSuggestions` function and neither of it fixed the problem.

```
public class SingleWifi extends AppCompatActivity {
private WifiManager wifiManager;
private Button disconnectButton;
List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> suggestionsList = new ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion>();

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_wifi);
    String wifiSSID = getIntent().getStringExtra("wifiList");
    connectToNetwork(wifiSSID);
    disconnectButton = findViewById(R.id.disconnectBtn);
    disconnectButton.setEnabled(false);
    disconnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            disconnectWifi();
            startActivity(new Intent(SingleWifi.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private void disconnectWifi() {
    if(wifiManager != null) {
        wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Disconnect successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private void connectToNetwork(String ssid) {
    final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
            .setSsid(ssid)
            .setWpa2Passphrase("password")
            .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true)
            .build();
    int statusCode = wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
    suggestionsList.add(suggestion);
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);

    if (status == WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(status == WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_ERROR_ADD_DUPLICATE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Already connected, update needed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        status = wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
        status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
    }

    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION);

    final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (!intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION)) {
                return;
            }
            // Post connection
            disconnectButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
}
```

removeNetworkSuggestions returns `0` so it does seem to produce the right output but does not seem to actually disconnect from the Internet.

Comment: please have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/58075918/8719734

Comment: @aryanagarwal I'm trying to disconnect from a WiFi network, not disable WiFi of my device. Are you suggesting even that's not possible?

Comment: That is possible and I think your approach is correct

Comment: @aryanagarwal Then I'm not sure why it's not getting disconnected. But if we go by disabling WiFi following your link, the action popup does not appear for me. What am I doing wrong? https://paste.ee/p/HC6VR

Comment: Do you use this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />` in manifest

Comment: @aryanagarwal Yes I do. I also tried manually going to settings and allowing the app to change WiFi state of device, that did not work either. Just saw that there is an active issue for this problem here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140398818

Comment: Did you found any solution? @Inception

Comment: any news ? I have the same issue @Inception

Comment: @Euphor08 Check my previous comment, it is an open and unresolved bug with Android 30 unfortunately.

Comment: @RahulSharma Check my previous comment, it is an open and unresolved bug with Android 30 unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going for a completely different implementation getting rid of the Wifinetworksuggestions API since this issue seem to be an unresolved bug as seen here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140398818 So sadly, there is no fix for this issue as of now.

Comment: Could you please share your implication approach? I am trying to make some improvements on https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/adb-wifi-setting-manager

Comment: same issue here, would love to learn how you ended up handling it

Comment: @BlueBot I didnt use the Wifinetworksuggestions API at all. Which means the desired feature of disconnecting did not work at all.

Comment: Yea I got it, meant how did you figure it out on the large scale - If you managed disconnect from a connected wifi in some other way/walk around/api? on API 30+